# Generating a combobox list based on a selection from another combobox C# (linked by Databases)

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, visual-studio, class

I am creating a Booking system for a Univeristy project using C# and WPF. I have completed a great majority of the project and now have a fully working update, delete and create new button for customers, bookings and guests. I store all data about Customers, Bookings and Guests within their own respective classes and in turn they then get saved to a database through a Connection Superclass.

Everything was working however, I started to implement Foreign keys into my database as to link the data together (and it works) but now my project is starting to look a little bit messy...

When creating a new booking, you must also choose a CustomerID from a ComboBox (cmbCustomerList), this allows the CustomerID_FK to be added to the same instance of BookingID. If you wish to edit the booking then you must select not only the cmbCustomerList but also the cmbBookingsList, however, if you try to update a BookingID with a new CustomerID_FK it throws an error, it also makes the program look messy as the Bookings ComboBox will show every booking no matter what CustomerID you chose. Does anyone know any way to make it so that when a CustomerID is selected from cmbCustomerList, it also only displays the BookingID's that have the same CustomerID_FK within cmbBookingsList?

Here is a copy of my Bookings window, I won't include my Bookings class because it's a simple collection of Get/Set methods, the main work is done within the NewBookings window and the Connection Class

### NewBookings.xaml.cs

```
//Refresh the items in cmbBookingsList
    public void BookingsRefresh()
    {
        cmbBookingsList.ItemsSource = con.RefreshBookingsList();
    }

//Refresh the items in cmbCustomerList
    public void CustomerRefresh()
    {
        cmbCustomerList.ItemsSource = con.RefreshCustomerList();
    }
```

### Connections.cs

```
//show customer information in the list
    public List<CustomerClass> RefreshCustomerList()
    {
        List<CustomerClass> CustomerList = new List<CustomerClass>();

        try
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            connection.Open();

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                CustomerClass c = new CustomerClass();

                c.Customer_ID = Convert.ToInt16(reader["CustomerID"].ToString());
                c.Customer_FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                c.Customer_Surname = reader["Surname"].ToString();
                c.Address_Line1 = reader["AddressLine1"].ToString();
                c.Address_Line2 = reader["AddressLine2"].ToString();
                c.City = reader["City"].ToString();
                c.Country = reader["Country"].ToString();

                CustomerList.Add(c);
            }
            return CustomerList;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

public List<BookingsClass> RefreshBookingsList()
    {
        List<BookingsClass> BookingsList = new List<BookingsClass>();

        try
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT BookingID, CheckIn, CheckOut, Dinner, Breakfast, CarHire, Diet FROM Bookings";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            connection.Open();

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                BookingsClass b = new BookingsClass();

                b.Booking_ID = Convert.ToInt16(reader["BookingID"].ToString());
                b.Arrival_Date = reader["CheckIn"].ToString();
                b.Departure_Date = reader["CheckOut"].ToString();
                b.Dinner = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["Dinner"]);
                b.Breakfast = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["Breakfast"]);
                b.CarHire = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["CarHire"]);
                b.DietaryReq = reader["Diet"].ToString();

                BookingsList.Add(b);
            }
            return BookingsList;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm sorry if this question is a bit broad or a bit complicated. I would much rather you left a comment telling me it isn't a good question rather than down voting, that way I will improve it and make it easier to understand

Comment: If you read yourself into MVVM, you'll realise that this can be easely abstracted as a logical action and it will be easy to bind both values to the controls.

Comment: At the time of writing this question, we were not allowed to use any other type of project other than WPF. We're learning MVVM now though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main issue you're having is that your trying to build a Winforms app in WPF

if you switch to an [MVVM structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh848246.aspx) it becomes much easier

then you would have your Combos bound to a DataField on your ViewModel
the view model would then update itself as required and the bindings will automatically update your view

here is a quick and dirty example

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BookingVM x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource vm}}">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" SelectedItem="{Binding Type}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" SelectedItem="{Binding Customer}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding Save, Mode=OneWay}">Save</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code (note using [Prism](https://pnpmvvm.codeplex.com/) and c# 6.0)

as i don't have your database to work with i'll create some example models that will do for demo purposes

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int[] BoodkingType { get; set; }
}
public class BoodkingTypeModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class DummyDatabase
{
    public static IEnumerable<BoodkingTypeModel> BoodkingTypes { get; } = new BoodkingTypeModel[]
    {
        new BoodkingTypeModel { ID=1, Name="Type1"  },
        new BoodkingTypeModel { ID=2, Name="Type2"  },
        new BoodkingTypeModel { ID=3, Name="Type3"  },
        new BoodkingTypeModel { ID=4, Name="Type4"  },
    };
    public static IEnumerable<CustomerModel> Customers { get; } = new CustomerModel[]
    {
        new CustomerModel { ID=1, Name="Customer1" ,BoodkingType= new int[]{ 1,2,3,4 } },
        new CustomerModel { ID=1, Name="Customer2" ,BoodkingType= new int[]{ 1,2 } },
        new CustomerModel { ID=1, Name="Customer3" ,BoodkingType= new int[]{ 3,4 } },
        new CustomerModel { ID=1, Name="Customer4" ,BoodkingType= new int[]{ 1 } },
    };

}
```

now this is the clever part the VM, that actually does all the work

```
public class BookingVM : BindableBase
{
    public BookingVM()
    {
        //Command binding in this situation is better than EventHandling as it allows you to specify requirements as well as actions
        //in this case that you can't save unless Type and Customer have been set
        Save = new DelegateCommand(
            () => Console.WriteLine("Save Clicked"), //ExecuteAction
            () => Type != null && Customer!=null //CanExecute
            );
    }
    private BoodkingTypeModel _Type;

    public BoodkingTypeModel Type
    {
        get { return _Type; }
        //this is triggered both when you change the values in the View via binding, and when you set the values via code meaning that you have a single point of entry so you don't need to check every place you alter the calue to be sure that its updates the control, also this value can be bound to no controls or 500 it doesn't matter its all handled automatically plus everything is now type safe very hard to do with generic controls
        set
        {
            if(SetProperty(ref _Type, value))
            {
                Save.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Customers));//instruct all bindings on customers to refresh
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<BoodkingTypeModel> Types
    {
        get { return DummyDatabase.BoodkingTypes; }
    }


    private CustomerModel _Customer;

    public CustomerModel Customer
    {
        get { return _Customer; }
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _Customer, value))//SetProperty changes the property if the value has change and raises the event that updates binding
            {
                Save.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();//refresh command state
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<CustomerModel> Customers
    {
        get
        {
            return from c in DummyDatabase.Customers
                   where Type == null || c.BoodkingType.Contains(Type.ID)
                   //the where clause is the link using the selected type to filter your customers
                   select c;
        }
    }
    public DelegateCommand Save { get;  }
}
```

the code in Prism, simplifies some of the more annoying tasks you have to do for every single class, so i highly recomend it however you could also write your own versions for very little effort

code for BindableBase can be seen [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs) the actual code is only about a dozen lines

Comment: I'm at a point in my project where a full redesign might not be doable. Can you suggest any other ways of doing this? Or would you mind specifying which parts of your code relate to my current problem? Really appreciate the help.

Comment: It shouldn't require a full redesign, your Connections.cs seems to be building a fair model so CustomerModel, BoodkingTypeModel, and DummyDatabase should have equivalents in your code that are specific to your needs, i just needed something quick for the demo, that leaves the View (XAML) which as you can see has no code and just the visuals and binding, and finally the ViewModel (BookingVM) most of the code for this should already be in your code behind file, just stand alone rather than closely coupled with the controls which actually simplifies everything massively

Comment: the only other option really is to purely winforms it, ie on the controls event handlers update all relevant controls manually, if you go down that route though i would suggest leaving out as much of the WPF sugar ( Binding, Templates,etc) as possible as the more you try and merge the two different styles the more unmanageable your code will be

Comment: thank you very much. I will mark your answer as correct